# ListView without queryset

Tags: django

I am trying to increase performance in a view that has to render a list of events. Currently, I populate a database table on the fly and with a generic list view I show it. However, since it has to do a dababase bulk insert it takes few seconds. I wonder if there is a way -since I have the information in a list in memory- to use the ListView not having to create the database table and the respective queryset. I mean to render the LisView directly from the list structure that I have in memory. Is it possible ?

I would appreciate if anyone can give me a hand with this since I have not found any information in google regarding this issue.

Best regards.

Comment: Of course it's possible: you can send anything directly to the template, and iterate over it. But you'll need to show an example of what you're doing, with some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Django's cache framework. From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/):

> To cache something is to save the result of an expensive calculation
>   so that you don’t have to perform the calculation next time.

If your database query is the expensive call, you can save time with each view rendering with caching. If you need to insert new data into the database, you can do that asynchronously using a task manager like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), so that the view renders without the need to wait for your DB activity.